# Ruby: Access instance variable of parent object

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I have a set of objects that themselves each create a bunch of helper objects. Inside of the helper objects I need access to many of the parents instance variables, such as "name", a logger object and some more.

I could initialize the helper objects with all of the needed variables but that seems quite tedious. Is there a way to make the parents instance variables known to all the objects owned by it?

I have found a wealth of similar questions but most are about class variables and inheritance so I was not able to find a solution yet.

Example & rubyfiddle:

```
class Helper
  def initialize()
  end

  def complexStuff
    puts # Parent object name
  end
end

class Main
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize( name )
    @name = name
    @helper = Helper.new
  end

  def update
    puts "[(#{name}).update]"
    @helper.complexStuff
  end
end

instance1 = Main.new( "Instance 1" )
instance2 = Main.new( "Instance 2" )

instance1.update
instance2.update
```

[**rubyfiddle**](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/ca7e5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just pass the parent in?

```
class Helper
  def initialize(parent)
    @parent = parent
  end

  def complexStuff
    puts @parent.name # Parent object name
  end
end

class Main
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize( name )
    @name = name
    @helper = Helper.new(self)
  end

  def update
    puts "[(#{name}).update]"
    @helper.complexStuff
  end
end

instance1 = Main.new( "Instance 1" )
instance2 = Main.new( "Instance 2" )

instance1.update
instance2.update
```